# Docker "cp" command in verbose mode

Tags: docker

I use to copy directories from host to containers extensively before pushing them to a repository. Sometimes we may need to monitor the filenames getting pushed/copied during the Jenkins build.

How can i see what files are getting copied during a copy operation using "docker cp" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing that docker provides but if your directories are empty then you can try and print what is there after the copy operation.

```
docker cp a b
docker exec container ls -alhR /your/path
```

Or you can print the same on the host side before copying. Because cp will only copy what you provide it. So either print it before or after copying. Before make more sense to me

Comment: I would like to go with checking/listing them on the container side, reason being people may play around with the pipeline & change the source path. However the destination path always remains same.

Comment: Yes, that's up to you. That is why I mentioned both possibilities

Comment: This works for me as if now but hoping to see some "-v" kind of thing for verbose mode integrated by default. Docker is using "-v" flag/option for volumes hence it should be something different than "-v" in case they want to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The diff command comes to mind.

> Inspect changes to files or directories on a container’s filesystem

```
username@pc:~$ docker cp /tmp/a.txt 23f117d36c3df11a5c899e3c814d7d6041a07f6eb430911e5d9da9be86fe6e5e:/tmp/a.txt 
username@pc:~$ docker diff 23f117d36c3df11a5c899e3c814d7d6041a07f6eb430911e5d9da9be86fe6e5e
C /tmp
A /tmp/a.txt
```

For further reference:

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/diff/#examples

Good point from Tarun is that this approach may mislead you if other activities happened.

Comment: this would also list everything that changed inside the container. Which may be the files that were actually not related to the copy operation

Comment: Sure. This in case that's the only activity we talk about which might or might not work for OP.